# Running out of disc space- how to check where its being used?

Tags: disk, disk-usage, delete, disk-management

I am starting to run out of disk space. How can I check where all the largest files are located on my Ubuntu installation so that I can delete them?

Answer (score 17):

You can use Disk Usage Analyzer (installed by default in Ubuntu). To use it just search **Disk Usage Analyzer** on dash (note that your icons may be different)

[image]

And then select the disk you want to scan. You will get a report similar this one

[image]

If you are using a CLI installation (ex: a server) or just prefer to use the terminal, you can try `ncdu`

```
 $ sudo apt-get install ncdu
 $ ncdu /
```

[image]

Comment: @user997112 If this is the answer you were looking for, please [accept the answer and remove your comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) .